# Version control and Android Library Projects

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, subclipse

When using [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) does anyone have a good solution for version control for projects that utilise these librarys?

For example if I have two apps, say a free version and paid, or phone and tablet, or any other scenario, and i want them to use some shared library's which are contained in an Android Lib Project, how can i safely add these projects to SVN? As they are seperate projects I have no way i know off enforcing that when one is committed the other (library one) is also.

I am using Eclipse with the Subclipse SVN plugin, does anyone know if there is a way to link the projects so a commit on one will commit the other?

Any tips here would be welcome - as I am relatively new to SVN - so may be thinking about this in the wrong way :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot enforce that both are committed at the same time (that's just not how SVN works), but you can still do it (by, as bigstones said, using Ctrl+Click or putting both of them in a Working Set, and committing that).

The way Android handles libraries is indeed quite flawed, and this is one of the reasons for it.

Comment: interesting - i should really look into working sets - can i treat that as a single entity and commit in one go? If i checkout will eclipse preserve working sets also?

Comment: Working Sets are a property of your Workspace, not of the individual projects, so they won't be checked in, except if you synchronize your entire Workspace. But thats probably not a good idea, since it usually contains a lot of user specific settings. To synchronize the Working Set, just right click on it and choose the appropriate option, like you would do for a project.

Comment: thanks for the responce. It seems a bit contradictory? Your saying you cannot check them in but you can synchronies them? I thought sync was an operation to perform before committing?

Comment: I see "synchronizing" as an combination of committing and updating. Basically, you can view Working Sets as a "saved selection" of projects. When you synchronize/update/commit the Working Set, you perform those operations on all selected projects. The information, which projects are combined to a Working Set will not be synchronized though, because it is stored in your Workspace folder, not in the synchronized project folders. Just try it out, its really much simpler than it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite new to versioning too, I'm using Subclipse too, I don't know if there's a way to commit both project and lib at once (if not selecting both with ctrl-click), but actually the "modified" icon is pretty visible and I never forgot about it.

The problem for me is that sometimes I modify the source opening it from the lib project, sometimes opening the source referenced in the app project, and I must remember to refresh the other. In case I forget it, in the second case, the lib project won't show the "modified" icon, so I end up refreshing both projects very often.